# How does drupal updates check work?

Tags: updating

I don't have an external crontab set up for my Drupal site.  How can Drupal search for updates in this case?

Comment: @close vote reviewers - come on, how is it unclear? Broad, maybe; basic, for sure; but unclear?

Answer (score 3):

There [**should** be a crontab task](https://drupal.org/cron) for Drupal. If there is none, it falls back to [Poormanscron](https://drupal.org/project/poormanscron) - integrated into Drupal core since 7.x

> The module inserts a small amount of JavaScript on each page of your site that when a certain amount of time has passed since the last cron run, calls an AJAX request to run the cron tasks. However, this approach requires that your site gets regular traffic/visitors in order to trigger the cron request.

When check is initiated, it loops over modules and checks their status from URLs determined in function `_update_build_fetch_url` define at line 287* of update.fetch.inc file, in *update* core module.

For more details, examine *update* core module, code is pretty well documented.

---

- Information valid for Drupal 7.25, may slightly change with version.

Comment: Thank you! Poormanscron - that is where the magic ("The module inserts a small amount of JavaScript on each page of your site that when a certain amount of time has passed since the last cron run, calls an AJAX request to run the cron tasks. However, this approach requires that your site gets regular traffic/visitors in order to trigger the cron request")

Comment: @Alexander But please read first link - Poormanscron is a bad solution. Better than nothing, sure, but still bad. Answer expanded with the quote you suggested.

Comment: I don't understand how to setup Cron. I see on admin/config/system/cron that it is enabled "every 3 hours" - is that all?.. what differences then between Poormanscron? or I must add something to my crontab file on unix system?

Comment: @Alexander to properly set up cron task, you must understand it's something you do on the server's operating system, outside Drupal. You must make your server to regularly call your Drupal and say "the time is now" ;) If possible, talk with your sysadmin.

Comment: I'm sysadmin) I just want to understand how does it work. I see on cron page that it is enabled and it regulary works off. Is it Poormanscron mechanism?.. In other words - if I close site from outside (no visitors) - cron task will not work? I think yes - no magic. But why it is better to make crontab task in operating system (something like curl or wget special address) then just use Poormanscron mechanism if it works fine?.. Even not popular sites robots visit regulary, so...